# Visual Studio Code - Formatting code styling

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am typing this in Visual Studio Code

```
const tours = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname/dev-data/data/tours-simple.json}`));
```

But when I save the file, my tours constant changes to this

```
const tours = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname / dev - data / data / tours - simple.json}`));
```

That makes my code non functional. How to remove the white spaces?

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing `}` character is in the wrong place. It's at the end of the string, when it should actually come right after the `__dirname` variable. Try this instead:

```
const tours = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data/tours-simple.json`));
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't writing the path in correctly - when you put it inside `${var}`, this denotes to JS that you want to escape that bracket from a string, and into a variable called `var`. JS will get the value of var and put it back into the string.

Example:

```
const a = 'a'
console.log(`${a}b`) // Prints 'ab'
```